# launch screen customising

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

I'm new to swift and Xcode, and I'd like to know is there anyone willing to explain to me how exactly should I make my launch screen to show for 3 seconds and in that time slightly fades out?

I want to do a web view of a web page that I built previously, but want it to do the launch screen with fading before.

I've read all other questions related to the topic, but I don't understand them. Also have been following some tutorials on the subject, but nothing.

Anyone, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do anything on your launch screen.But try this out and see if it's okay. Let's say you want to give a fade-in animation for an image in the launch. Let's assume that your launchscreen background color is blue. Make another viewcontroller and make this the first viewcontroller right after the launch screen. Make the background color of this view blue and add the image to that view. You can animate the image with `UIView.animate` method with a delay of 3 seconds or something. Doing this will make it look like an animation in the launch screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in the launch screen.

That is not what the launch screen is for.

If you want to do this you will have to create a secondary "launch" screen that your app loads first and then load the web view and when it's loaded push another view onto the screen,

Comment: I've considered that too, but I still don't know how to do it :/
I know how to add and style the views I want to show, but making the code for it is the problem. 
Can you help in any way?